# Action not displaying in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, administration, lightning-experience

I have a Lightning App record detail page (The one where you drag and drop). I've created a new Action to display on the highlights panel.

In the SFDC Classic page layout, I've added the action to the section "Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience Actions". However, it doesn't display on the highlight panels. I have a few other actions which I've created in the same way and they display just fine. I can change the order of the actions and they change immediately on the lightning app record detail page so I know it's updating properly.

Any suggestions as to why it's not displaying my action?

Thanks!

In the list below, I'm expecting to see "New Contact Report" in the dropdown list since I've added it to the layout. However the second picture shows it doesn't have it. 
[image: Buttons]

[image: Actions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it was not showing was because the related objects had record types and the record types were not selected in the profile. Instead, it was set as "Master". When I selected the record types, they showed up.

Comment: I have same problem. I did not understand your solution. Can you please explain more to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 12):

If the highlight panel you're attempting to add actions to is for Case, note that Quick Actions added to the Case highlight panel actually appear on the `Feed` tab on the layout.

> Actions on cases and work orders appear in a different way than on
> other records. On case and work order records, the page-level action
> menu contains custom buttons and supported standard buttons. Quick
> actions appear on the Feed tab.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_in_lex.htm&type=5